# Flask form SelectField

Tags: python, post, flask, get

My app.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from wtforms import SelectField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


def Form(FlaskForm):
    panel_brand = SelectField('Panel Brand',choices=[('tr','trina'),('lo','longi'), ('ph','phono'), ('leap','leapton')])
    mounting = SelectField('Mounting',choices=[('tr','trina'),('lo','longi'), ('ph','phono'), ('leap','leapton')])
    inverter = SelectField('inverter',choices=[('Fronius10','Fronius 10'),('Fronius5','Fronius 5'), ('huawei6','huawei 6'), ('huawei8','huawei 8') , ('SolarEdge125','SolarEdge 12,5')])
    order_fulfillment = SelectField('orderfulfillment',choices=[('all3','Panels + inverter + mounting'),('Panels','Panels'),('panelsinv','Panels + Inverter'),('installer','By Installer')])


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = Form(FlaskForm)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.panel_brand }}
        {{ form.mounting }}
        {{ form.inverter }}
        {{ form.order_fulfillment }}
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app.py file It just shows me the submit button and not the expected dropdowns `panel_brand`, `mounting`, `inverter`, `order_fulfillment`- which has the subsequent values. I guess I am missing some calling ids in the `index()` function? I am not sure how to do that in proper syntax. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a function where it needs to have a class.

Change

```
def Form(FlaskForm):
...
form = Form(FlaskForm)
```

to

```
class Form(FlaskForm)
...
form = Form(request.form)
```

and

Comment: Expand on "didn't work". What does the rendered HTML for the form look like?

Comment: I am sorry. It gives an error now `RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF.` . Do you know what is it?

Comment: See "When using a FlaskForm" in https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html

Comment: Just figured out the secret key thingy! Thank you so much! :) Your ans of replacing def to class helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `form` declaration is subclassing another object.

Try:

```py
def index():
    form = Form(request.form)
```

Comment: As Dave mentioned, your `Form` is declared as a function. Change it to a class, as he suggested.